# Change colour of a QGIS layer derived from import of a DWG

Tags: qgis, dwg

When I use QGIS to import layers of a DWG drawing to a gpkg, the corresponding layer seems to retain the colour it had in the DWG, and any subsequent changes to the symbology of the layer in terms of line colour (or thickness) seems to be ignored.

Is there another way to change how these layers are presented?

Answer (score 4):

The gpkg import has colour and line thickness data from the dxf stored in fields, which are used to set the layer symbology in qgis by using a data defined override. To set your own colours, etc you need to disable the relevant data defined overrides in the symbology.